# Cosmos DB : collection & atomic counter

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB and a collection like this one :

```
{
  "name" : "Marc Zukerberg",
  "follower" : "100"
}
```

I'm looking for a way to increment the 'follower' count, but in an ***ATOMIC*** way, because a lot of increment can occur at the same time !

Is it possible ?

Is there some patterns for such cases in NoSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each document in CosmosDB has a set of System Properties.

One of them is the `etag`. The `etag` is a property who's value changes every time the document itself changes in some way.

This can be used to provide optimistic concurrency control.

This can be achieved by using the `AccessCondition` object with your Operations such as `Replace`.

That way you can guarantee that the `etag` matches which means that the document didn't change while you are doing your update operation.

An example on how you can do this in detail can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L431).

Comment: Really nice, but is there a way to do this in one operation. Is there a way to execute some operations on a document ? (Javascript, store procedure etc). If I'm right, the storedprocedure problem is that they are per collection partition :! Thanks

Comment: @Nick Chapsas, CosmosDB has different isolation levels. Is `etag` eventually consistent if I'm using a lax consistency model?

Comment: I'm really unsure how this answered the OPs question... The question was around atomic operations... Replace is an optimistic update, if etag changes you have to refetch the document which kills high concurrency updates.

Comment: I agree with @VulgarBinary, this should not have been accepted answer by OP. Opening another question will be duplicate.. It seems like your answer doesn't even match the subject of the question..

Comment: @formatc - there is a better way now per the other answer

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the answer to be a `Patch` operation.

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.patchitemasync?view=azure-dotnet).

> The patch operations are atomic and are executed sequentially. By default, resource body will be returned as part of the response. User can request no content by setting EnableContentResponseOnWrite flag to false.

Comment: Yep, patch has an "increment" operation specifically for this type of thing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.patchoperation.increment?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-patchoperation-increment(system-string-system-double). Patch didn't exist when this question was asked (2018)